# How to open current activity with android notification?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I would like to have a notification open the activity from which it is created. I am using ActionBarSherlock and my code looks like this:

```
public class CurrentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private void remindMeAlert() {      
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CurrentActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("text")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();

    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti); 

    }
}
```

This does not make any action when pressing the notification. However if I open any other activity like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DifferentActivity.class);
```

It works fine.

Comment: Problem should be with CurrentActivity

Comment: use broadcast receiver to get any action of this current activity